# use RSA encrypt/decrypt for client/server side on unity and node js

Tags: c#, node.js, unity-game-engine, socket.io, rsa

i working on a Online game with Unity and Node JS.

i used **Node-RSA** in my node js (server side) for Encrypt and Decrypt messages.
i create public key and private key in hear now i have this two keys on server.

now i want to make same keys in C# (unity) for Decrypt messages and Encrypt message for send to server.
in c# i used

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider
```

create this two `RSAParameters`

```
private RSAParameters PrivateKey;
private RSAParameters PublickKey;
```

but i don't now how can i change key value in them an put my server keys into them.

Comment: You should use [KeyObject](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_keyobject) class and the export function, with pcks8 type. PKCS #8 is for storing private key information. You should then import this in your .net project

Comment: do you mean this key?
`const key=new noodrsa({b:512});`
`var pubkeykey.exportKey('public');`
`var privk= key.exportKey('private');`

i mean i have this keys as private/public keys it stored on my `node.js`  but i can't see this var information to use them in my .net.

Answer (score 0):

try it in node js

```
 const NodeRSA   = require('node-rsa');
 const key       = new NodeRSA('-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----PRIVATE_key----- 
 END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----");
 const text = 'helo';
 const encrypted = key.encrypt(text, 'base64');
 console.log('encrypted: ', encrypted);
```